# unable to connect to flask app when changing host

Tags: flask, localhost

I have a flask web service app connected to a mongodb database using pymongo which performs basic create , read , update , delete operations . I can run my app using

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=3000)
```

However if I change `host = '0.0.0.0'` I am denied entry to my flask app when I search `http://0.0.0.0:3000/` in chrome as I get

```
the web page at might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address
```

I would appreciate your help with guiding me to solve this issue .
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to indicate the `local ip address` of your machine `192.168.x.y` instead of `0.0.0.0`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='192.168.x.y', port=3000)
```